# MySQL Workbench invert relationship

Tags: mysql-workbench

How to invert relationship in MySQL Workbench. And also explain how to relate the table without any new fields like "(reservation_reservation_id)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to invert a relationship. You have to delete and recreate it in the reverse direction. Use the relationship tools from the vertical palette to quickly do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can invert a relationship now using the Relationship Editor by double clicking on a relationship line.

Comment: which version number?

Comment: I'm using Workbench 8.0 CE

Comment: ok thanks. I'm using an older version and that option isn't there. I thought I was going crazy :)

Comment: i can't see that and I have 8.0 on MacOS

Comment: use 8.x its better